# Classes and Subclasses Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I am trying to learn Classes and Subclasses. So, I started with this…

```
class Class1:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.valx = "With Class1"


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Result: %s - %s " % (self.name, self.valx)


option1 = Class1("Paul")
print(option1)
```

Result: **Paul - With Class1**

But now, I want to work with a **Subclass** and set the value of valx to With Class1 or With Class2 in relation to Class or Subclass.

**I want to reach or obtain this**

```
option1 = Class1("Paul")
print(option1)
```

Result: **Paul - With Class1**

```
option2 = Class2("Paul")
print(option2)
```

Result: **Paul - With Class2**

**My idea was to add**

```
class Class2(Class1):
    self.valx = "With Class2"
```

But I doesn´t work and I´m trying all what my mind can without results.
Anyone can help me?

Remember that I´m learning! 
Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `__init__` method in `Class2`:

```
class Class2(Class1):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name) # call __init__ of super class
        self.valx = "With Class2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great! I did not find that in the tutorials that I am following. Thanks and more. Happy Holidays!